# File search based different approach

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I was having one requirement that is I have to write a high performance file search program, the program is supposed to list down all the files and folder that matches the name pattern provided starting from the topmost folder and searching recursively in subfolders.

program can be command line main class with the following input

The top folder to start search . example that is C:\MyFolders
Type of item to search. File or folder or both
Search pattern java regular expression (java.util.regex) are accepted as paatern

example *MFile*.tx? will find UMFile123.txt and AIIMFile.txs'
Timeout (in secs) by which application must return. otherwise it must return with "could not complete operation " message.

I have come up with anoter approach that is..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.sapient.test.fileSearch.FileSearch;

public class FilesearchMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int flag=0;
        System.out.println("Type Item to Search ");
        System.out.println("1 File");
        System.out.println("2 Folder ");
        System.out.println("3 Both");
        System.out.println("0 Exit");

        try{
        BufferedReader readType = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        String searchType =readType.readLine();;

        System.out.println("Enter name of file to search ::");

        BufferedReader readName = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fileName=readName.readLine();


        if(searchType==null && fileName==null){
            throw new Exception("Error Occured::Provide both the input Parameters");
        }
        validateInputs(searchType,fileName);
        FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch(searchType,fileName);
List resultList=fileSearch.findFiles();
        System.out.println(resultList);
        }catch(IOException io){
            System.out.println("Error Occured:: Check the input Parameters and try again");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void validateInputs(String searchType, String fileName) 
    throws Exception{
        if(!(searchType.equals("1") || searchType.equals("2") || searchType.equals("3")) ){
            throw new Exception("Error:: Item to search can be only 1 or 2 or 3");
        }
        if(searchType.equals("") || fileName.equals("")){
            System.out.println("Error Occured:: Check the input Parameters and try again");

        }

    }

}
```

the other file is...

```
public class FileSearch {
    private String searchType;
    private String fileName;

    public FileSearch(){

    }
    public FileSearch(String sType,String fName){
        this.searchType=sType;
        this.fileName=fName;
    }

    public String getSearchType() {
        return searchType;
    }
    public void setSearchType(String searchType) {
        this.searchType = searchType;
    }
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public List findFiles(){

        File file = new File("C:\\MyFolders");

        return searchInDirectory(file);

    }
    //Assuming that files to search should contain the typed name by the user
    //
    private List searchInDirectory(File dirName){
        List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(dirName.isDirectory()){
            File [] listFiles = dirName.listFiles();
            for(File searchedFile : listFiles){
                if(searchedFile.isFile() && searchedFile.getName().toUpperCase().contains(getFileName().toUpperCase())&& 
                        (getSearchType().equals("1") || getSearchType().equals("3") ) ){
                    filesList.add(searchedFile.getName());
                }else if(searchedFile.isDirectory() && searchedFile.getName().toUpperCase().contains(getFileName().toUpperCase())
                    &&  (getSearchType().equals("2") || getSearchType().equals("3") ) ){
                    filesList.add(searchedFile.getName());
                    searchInDirectory(searchedFile);
                }else{
                    searchInDirectory(searchedFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return filesList;
    }

}


Please advise is this approach is correct as per design..!Please update ..!1
```

Comment: @JonLin.. the same mention at top of my question and this is my approach please tell whether it is correct

Comment: I know you've tagged this with `Java`, so won't propose this as an answer. But Java is the wrong tool here.  First you can get from the GnuWin32 project or Cygwin a version of *nix `find` that will do this.  Or you can use Perl `File::Find`. I expect there are similar packages for other scripting languages.  Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

No. You are stating you want to like to search for regex, which you are not doing, since you are only comparing it with `contains`. If this is more than a simple excercise, you might want to have a look at the methods `File.listFiles()` and [Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`PatternFilenameFilter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/PatternFilenameFilter.html). If you really want to limit the time that the program can run have a look at Guava's [`SimpleTimeLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter.html). However, as Gene said in her comment, other tools might be more appropriate if just a simple `find`-like tool is required.